# How to attach gdb to android emulator in chrome ARC

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome-arc, ndk-gdb

I need to attach gdb to debug my android app in chrome ARC. After loading the adb plugin, I can see the device listed in "adb devices" however I can't start a gdb server on this emulator. Same thing happens with Android studio which is not able to detect ARC emulator. Is there an easy way to debug the android app in ARC for java and native side code? Till so far, I've relying mostly on logcat traces but due to complexity of the app, it's getting difficult to completely rely on logcat traces.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. ARC does not currently support debugging apps with gdb. We do not have a gdb server running in ARC.

Feel free to [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) to express your interest in such a feature.